# Is that possible to encrypt the traffic which is between internal webservers by using Load Balancer

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, https, haproxy, lets-encrypt

I am currently using Let's Encrypt to obtain server certificates for approximately 100+ backend servers. Every 90 days I have to work with other teams to renew my certs via the DNS-01 challenge. I found a solution about Load Balancer that sounds like I only have to do the DNS-01 challenge in the
load balancer then all traffic will be encrypted:

SSL termination encrypts outside traffic in front of the load balancer. If we would like to encrypt the traffic between the load balancer and the internal webserver we may have an SSL pass-through. But how about the traffic between our internal webserver(backend server)?

If I implement a load balancer in the middle, is that possible to encrypt the traffic between the internal webserver if we decide to implement SSL termination or SSL pass-through?

I am very new to Load Balancer, any help is appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by "traffic between internal webserver"?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Sorry for the confusion. I mean our internal servers that are behind the load balancer.  They are in our LAN and could be in the same VLAN.

Comment: Well ... use HTTPS? What has this to do with the load balancer?

Comment: How do the internal webservers communicate with each other?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Sorry for the confusion. I updated my question, I would like to know how do I handle the traffic between backend servers if I only have a wildcard SSL certificate with the load balancer.

Comment: @Charm_quark HTTPS with FQDN and port  443. We don't allow IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always encrypt traffic between any systems which belong to a defined group. *IPsec transport mode* is created specifically for that. It is not important which roles those servers assume, backend, frontend, etc., they are just IP nodes in this case. Consider this as a generic solution which makes "yes, it is possible" a valid answer for all questions like "is that possible to encrypt traffic between A and B". However, sometimes it is not convenient and so often there are other options.

---

Other options depend on *for which purpose* you need this encryption. Don't answer "just for security", there is no such thing as "just security". There are threat models and there are security models that cope with those defined threats. For example, in simple terms the threat model for the HTTP is the man in the middle who can eavedrop and inject its own data, impersonate itself as a valid server and/or a valid client; the HTTPS is designed to make this impossible by encrypting and signing all communication. MitM at best can either pass all the traffic without being able to eavedrop or just disrupt communication altogether. So, what *you* are defending against, what are your threats?

Your network between the backends and balancers is not trusted? Why? Those networks should include only balancers and backends and nothing else, which untrusted actors do you have there? However, IPsec in transport mode is acceptable solution in this case, because it will encrypt everything on the wire.

You can also use HTTPS between balancer and backends (and between backends themselves). That's OK, your balancer will terminate user HTTPS, see the request and reply in plain text, able to mangle them (add/remove/change headers), and able to select the backend and processing by analyzing contents, for example, select one backend for static and other for dynamic content. Then it will establish *another* HTTPS connection to backend. The only HTTPS clients for backends will be balancers and other backends, so it is not important for them to use globally recongized certificates. (For example, Google Frontends don't check certificates of HTTPS backends located inside Google Cloud, so even self-signed certificates will work.) You may create your own internal CA, issue certificates for all backends and balancers and make them trusted by installing that CA certificate in each system's store. Only the balancers need to have configured globally valid certificates and only on the client-facing side. Let's Encrypt automation will likely to be also the duty of those balancers, because issued certificates are to be installed on them.

You don't trust your load balancer? SSL passthrough could help, but it has its own drawbacks too. In this setup the balancer is one of those men in the middle against whom the HTTPS was created. So it can't access the HTTP details to balance requests upon, even know the http Host header value to differentiate vhosts; it can't inject additional proxy headers like those "proxied for", and so on; connections are protected from it as expected. All it could do is to hopefully track the connection and otherwise blindly forward packets to some backend. In this case you don't configure any certificates on it and even don't configure any server names. Just specify IPs of backends. Also, in this case valid certificates must be installed on all backends, because it is not known a priori which backend will get which request.